x/y and y/x having different-sized parentheses
I wrapped \dfrac xy and \dfrac yx in left and right LaTeX tags with parentheses, and I expected that the parentheses would be the same size since x/y and y/x should technically be the same height. However, x/y is bigger than y/x - why? Is there any way that I can fix them to be the same size?
\left(\dfrac xy\right)\left(\dfrac yx\right)


y has a descender. In general avoid using \left\right for such constructs, use \bigl(...\bigr)  and avoid using \dfrac in most cases \frac should automatically use display style when needed.

you still get worse horizontal space with \left and a strut @JohnKormylo

\left \right does not guarantee equal size and guarantees poorer horizontal white space as it forces \mathinner spacing rather than \mathopen and \mathclose spacing.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)
\]

\[
  \Bigl(\frac{x}{y}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{y}{x}\Bigr)
\]

\end{document}


David already explained that y has a descender in opposite to x. This makes the denominator bigger leading to larger parentheses.
Another way to get the same size of the parentheses is to use \vphantom. It creates an empty box with the vertical dimensions (depth and height) of the argument:
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$ \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \left(\frac{y}{x\vphantom{y}}\right) $
\end{document}


